# slack scim api - using the FILTER parameter

Tags: slack-api, scim

I'm trying to use the `filter` parameter in a RESTful GET request, via this Slack API:

https://api.slack.com/scim

The Docs read:

**GET /Users** -
Returns a list of Users in a paginated fashion. Use startIndex and count query parameters to change pagination results. **Supports the *filter* parameter.**

Every attempt at using the `filter` parameter appended to the request URL, via `https://api.slack.com/scim/v1/Users?filter=userName` returns this error:

```
{"Errors":{"description":"no_filters","code":400}}
```

Anyone aware of a standardized way that the filter parameter is used in API URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They use this format below separated by spaces (%20) . Example without quotes

"email%20co%20jane.doe@somewhere.com"

"userName%20eq%20joe.schmoe"

eq  equal   The attribute and operator values must be identical for a match.
co  contains    The entire operator value must be a substring of the attribute value for a match.
sw  starts with The entire operator value must be a substring of the attribute value, starting at the beginning of the attribute value. This criterion is satisfied if the two strings are identical.
pr  present (has value) If the attribute has a non-empty value, or if it contains a non-empty node for complex attributes there is a match.
gt  greater than    If the attribute value is greater than operator value, there is a match. The actual comparison is dependent on the attribute type. For string attribute types, this is a lexicographical comparison and for DateTime types, it is a chronological comparison.
ge  greater than or equal   If the attribute value is greater than or equal to the operator value, there is a match. The actual comparison is dependent on the attribute type. For string attribute types, this is a lexicographical comparison and for DateTime types, it is a chronological comparison.
lt  less than   If the attribute value is less than operator value, there is a match. The actual comparison is dependent on the attribute type. For string attribute types, this is a lexicographical comparison and for DateTime types, it is a chronological comparison.
le  less than or equal  If the attribute value is less than or equal to the operator value, there is a match. The actual comparison is dependent on the attribute type. For string attribute types, this is a lexicographical comparison and for DateTime types, it is a chronological comparison.

Comment: Thank you. Surprisingly, this worked! Is this documented anywhere? I feel like I searched forever and wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I don't know why Slack doesn't have this in their documentation

Answer (score 2):

Slack doesn't have anything in their documentation on how to use the Filter part of the SCIM User API. The SCIM Draft standard they link to on https://api.slack.com/scim contains the information in section 3.2.2.1 - http://www.simplecloud.info/specs/draft-scim-api-00.html#query-resources

Comment: Hi, this answer links to some helpful resources which do answer the question, but it's a good idea to include the main points in your answer in case the links become inaccessible later.